# Phantom EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, memory

Every other BAD_ACCESS I had before was usually a quick typo fix, but this one is very confusing

This code is supposed to download a .ics google calendar file and then pass it into a parser function, that will return an array of Event objects (not included here)

The problem is, when tested on a physical iOS device, every 3rd-4th run of loadEventIntoCalendar() an EXC_BAD_ACCESS is thrown when this line is called

`tempHold = calendarString.substring(with: tempRange)`

in the while loop of the event() function.

I tried solving this issue with many different techniques. 
Zombie objects straight up do not print anything in the log.
I tried analyzing the runs with *Instruments* but I didn't find anything useful there. I tried making a separate copy of the String file passed in the arguments but that did not change anything.

I'm positive that the issue has something to do with calendarString, or at least the value that that is pointing to. I tried analyzing the memory blocks through Xcode but I could not find any variables, that would point to the memory location that is causing the error.

I'm pretty sure that RAM would not be overloaded as the whole app only takes up about 70 Megabytes max (Checked with *Instruments*)

events() is supposed to be a singleton static function.

Here are the two functions

```
func loadEventsIntoCalendar() {
    // The link from which the calendar is downloaded
    let url = URL (string: "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/wlmacci%40gmail.com/public/basic.ics")!


    // The process of downloading and parsing the calendar
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        // The following is simply a declaration and will not execute without the line 'task.resume()'
        if let URLContent = data {  // If Data has been loaded
            // If you got to this point then you've downloaded the calendar so...
            // Calendar File parsing starts here!!!
            // The string that holds the contents of the calendar's events
            var webContent:String = String(data: URLContent, encoding:String.Encoding.utf8)!
            self.events(forCalendarFile: &webContent, inCalendar: Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian))
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

// Calendar Parser for this VC
func events(forCalendarFile webContent:inout String, inCalendar calendar:Calendar) {
    // The reason for this complication is, i thought copying the object might solve the issue, it did not :(
    let NSWebContent = NSString(string: webContent)
    let calendarString = NSWebContent.copy() as! NSString

    // An array of flags used for locating the event fields
    // [h][0] - The flag that marks the begining of a field, [h][1] - The flag that marks the end of a field
    let searchTitles:[[String]] = [["SUMMARY:", "TRANSP:"], ["DESCRIPTION:", "LAST-MODIFIED:"], ["DTSTART", "DTEND"], ["DTEND", "DTSTAMP"], ["LOCATION:", "SEQUENCE:"]]

    // The range of "webContent's" content that is to be scanned
    // Must be decreased after each event is scanned
    var range:NSRange = NSMakeRange(0, calendarString.length - 1)
    // Inside function that will be used to determine the 'difference' range between the begining and end flag ranges.
    let findDifference:(NSRange, NSRange) -> NSRange = {(first:NSRange, second:NSRange) -> NSRange in
        let location = first.location + first.length, length = second.location - location   // Determine the start position and length of our new range
        return NSMakeRange(location, length)                                                // Create and return the new range
    }
    // Inside function that will be used to move the searching range to the next event
    // Returns an NSNotFound range (NSNotFound, 0) if there are no more events
    let updateRange:(NSRange) -> NSRange = {(oldRange:NSRange) -> NSRange in
        let beginingDeclaration = calendarString.range(of: "BEGIN:VEVENT", options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: oldRange)
        // If the "BEGIN:VEVENT" was not found in webContent (no more events)
        if NSEqualRanges(beginingDeclaration, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)) {
            return beginingDeclaration  // Return an 'NSNotFound' range (Named it myself;)
        }
        // Calculate the index of the last character of 'beginingDeclaration' flag
        let endOfBeginingDeclaration = beginingDeclaration.location + beginingDeclaration.length
        // Calculate the length of the new range
        let length = oldRange.length - endOfBeginingDeclaration + oldRange.location
        // Calculate the starting location of the new range
        let location = endOfBeginingDeclaration
        // Create and return the new range
        return NSMakeRange(location, length)
    }

    // A holder for the begining and end flags for each event field
    var fieldBoundaries:[NSRange]
    // The actual parsing of each event
    repeat {
        range = updateRange(range)  // Move our searching range to the next event
        if NSEqualRanges(range, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)) {   // If there are no more events in the searching range
            break;                                              // Then no more shall be added (break from the loop)
        }

        var tempHold:String!
        // Record each field into our event database
        for h in 0...searchTitles.count-1 {
            fieldBoundaries = [NSRange]()   // Clear the fieldBoundaries for the new search
            fieldBoundaries.append(calendarString.range(of: searchTitles[h][0], options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: range))   // Find the begining flag
            fieldBoundaries.append(calendarString.range(of: searchTitles[h][1], options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range: range))   // Find the ending flag
            let tempRange = findDifference(fieldBoundaries[0], fieldBoundaries[1])
            print ("Isolating event content")
            tempHold = calendarString.substring(with: tempRange)                         // Create a new string from whatever is in between the two flags. This will be the current field of the event
            print ("Event content isolated")
            tempHold = tempHold.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.newlines)                                           // Remove all /r /n and other 'new line' characters from the event field
            tempHold = tempHold.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{005C}", with: "", options: .literal, range: nil)           // Replace all backslashes from the event field
        }
    } while (true)
}
```

This has to be completed relatively soon, so quick responses will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the line `tempHold = calendarString.substring(with: tempRange)` or logging `tempRange` and `calendarString` just before it?

Comment: The problem was that some of the components inside the memory were getting corrupted half-way through the run, so a breakpoint wouldn't show me much except for a completely live variable at one point and a corrupted one at the next. Doesn't show me the source of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what I ended up doing is completely rewriting the algorithm. It works in a bit of a different manner and is actually 20 lines shorter and much faster now.

Thanks for the attention though! Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the string searching methods don't guarantee the length of the resulting range to be `0`. What happens if you replace the two range checks?

```
if range.location == NSNotFound { ... }
```

instead of

```
if NSEqualRanges(range, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)) { ... }
```

Comment: As far as I know, NSNotFound is a number, not a range, so I don't think that line will work, but thanks anyway.